# Foreach with if/else outside it's function

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, joomla3.0

I'am creating a Joomla Template (Joomla 3) well some of you may have experience with this, and will recognize the problem I got. When you insert Modules in to you template and leave them empty, it's still uses some space. To prevent this i would like to add a variable CSS class. As solution used a array with an if else:

*Array for module positions*

```
$modules = array(1 => 'modulename', 'modulename2', 'modulename3');
```

*Foreach modulename which is 0 set display to none*

```
foreach ($modules as $module)
    if ($this->countModules($module) == '0') {
        $display = ' display-block';
    } else {
        $display = ' display-none';
    }

<section class="<?php echo $display['modulename'] ?>">   
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="modulename" />
</section>
```

Is it possible to link $display with the $display['modulename'] since their are more array's ? Is there a sort of ID to link from my foreach to my ['modulename']?

Comment: there is some problem with your code. `$display` is not an array so `$display['modulename']` will not work.

Comment: Okay is it possible when the if/else function is ended. To use him at section with his modulename, since theyre more arrays to be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to check if module count is 0? if it's 0 then you will hide the module right? With this code you can accomplish that.

```
$moduleDisplays = array();
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    if ($this->countModules($module) == '0') {
        $moduleDisplays[$module] = ' display-block';
    } else {
        $moduleDisplays[$module] = ' display-none';
    }
}

<section class="<?php echo $moduleDisplays['modulename'] ?>">   
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="modulename" />
</section>
```

Another method:

```
$moduleDisplays = array();
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $moduleDisplays[$module] = ($this->countModules($module) == '0') ? ' display-block' : ' display-none';
}

<section class="<?php echo $moduleDisplays['modulename'] ?>">   
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="modulename" />
</section>
```

Comment: That's what i wanted. Thank's alot!

Comment: A shorter notation, always in for that. Double thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a class that determines whether or not the module is displayed, why not simply add the html in your `if` statement like so:

```
<?php
  foreach ($modules as $module) {
      if ($this->countModules($module) == '0') { ?>
          <section>   
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="modulename" />
          </section>
      <?php } else {
          $display = '';
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Because i need to include a lot of code each time, and their a lot of different position's. Excuse me if i am wrong. Also i need to choose from where on i am going to hide the div in my HTML.